# Using QuickOSM to select more values in key?

Tags: quickosm

In using QGIS, I would like to select several values at once within the same key in QuickOSM.

I'm not at all familiar with coding!

Can someone suggest a simple point-by-point method to do this?

An example would be:

- In Quick Queries, I select "amenities" under Key. Under Value, I'd like to select colleges, schools, hospitals.

Is there a way to do this, so that I don't have to do one at a time?

Answer (score 3):

The QuickOSM plugin dialogue also has an option to use a query from the Overpass Turbo API.

http://overpass-turbo.eu/

Here I can construct a query to find amenities = bench and townhall using the wizard:

```
amenity = bench or amenity = townhall
```

The query runs and the results show, but the code to run this shows on the side:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“amenity = bench or amenity = townhall”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=bench”
  node["amenity"="bench"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="bench"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="bench"]({{bbox}});
  // query part for: “amenity=townhall”
  node["amenity"="townhall"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="townhall"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="townhall"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Simply copy and paste that query code into the Query pane in QuickOSM, then click Run Query:

[image]

If you don't get all the geometry types returning, open up the 'advanced' section to ensure all geometry types are set. At first all geometry types weren't returned. When I opened the 'advanced' tab - without changing anything - and ran the query again, all geometry types came back.

Comment: I tried this method, but it only yielded points. (I'm searching for hospitals, schools, and colleges as polygons.) When I used "Advanced" to specify Multipolygons, there were no results. Yet when I run the Quick Query on any one of these, I do get polygons. What am I leaving out?

Comment: @CSyrett have you used OSM to determine those are the exact tags?

Comment: I have no idea what a "tag" is. All I know is that the query shows the polygons, points, and lines on the Overpass Turbo display, but the same query, copy-pasted to Quick Query, only yields points. It appears that the same query behaves differently from one to the other.

Comment: @CSyrett can you share the query you're using?

Comment: here it is:

The original search was:
“amenity = college or amenity = school”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=college”
  node["amenity"="college"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="college"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="college"]({{bbox}});
  // query part for: “amenity=school”
  node["amenity"="school"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="school"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="school"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;

Comment: @CSyrett figured it out - go into the 'advanced' area under the query - don't change anything (just ensure all the geometry types are checked for results) - try to run the query again - mine is now working for points, LINES and polygons too...

Comment: I tried that right from the start. Just tried again now. No polygons. Can you screenshot the query result box?

Comment: @CSyrett I ran it again this morning but no luck - seems its very finicky...

Comment: Repeated attempts are still unsuccessful. What does work is simply downloading the OSM area outside of QGIS, opening the OSM as a layer, and running searches!

Answer (score 1):

One workaround could be:

1. Generate query with the Quick query menu and one of the values, e.g. Key:amenity, Value:college.
2. Switch to the Query window, copy and paste the query tags and replace the parameter v="college" with v="school".
3. Repeat with v="hospital"
   See example (only for nodes):

```xml
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="25">
    <union>
        <query type="node">
            <has-kv k="amenity" v="college"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
<query type="node">
            <has-kv k="amenity" v="school"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
<query type="node">
            <has-kv k="amenity" v="hospital"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="amenity" v="college"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
        <query type="relation">
            <has-kv k="amenity" v="college"/>
            <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
        </query>
    </union>
    <union>
        <item/>
        <recurse type="down"/>
    </union>
    <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For future look outs: you are looking in the wrong place with your query. You want to query for buildings.

```xml
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="25">
    <id-query {{geocodeArea:Oldenburg, Germany}} into="area_0"/>
    <union>
        <query type="node">
            <has-kv k="building" v="hotel"/>
            <area-query from="area_0"/>
        </query>
        <query type="way">
            <has-kv k="building" v="hotel"/>
            <area-query from="area_0"/>
        </query>
        <query type="relation">
            <has-kv k="building" v="hotel"/>
            <area-query from="area_0"/>
        </query>
    </union>
    <union>
        <item/>
        <recurse type="down"/>
    </union>
    <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```